TinyMCE: Cursor Does Not Move to Next Line After Inserting Content with <br> Tag Using mceInsertContent
I'm using TinyMCE for my rich text editor, and I'm performing clipboard operations to insert content into the editor using the mceInsertContent command. When I insert content that ends with a  tag, for example, the string "text", the content is inserted correctly, but the cursor does not move to the next line as expected. (I had copied this content from notepad. The content was a line called "test" and then I had hit enter after that, so a new line below the string "test")
Here is a simplified version of my code:
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#editor',
    setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        let textContent = clipboardData.getData('Text'); //Got the data as "text\r\n"

        // Replace new lines with <br/>
        textContent = textContent.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br/>"); //now, "text<br/>"

        // Insert the modified content into the editor
        editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, textContent);
    });
}

});
I expect after this execution, I want the line text inserted and the cursor blinking in the next line so when I start entering text it should start in the next line after the string "test".
Tested this in Tinymce JS fiddle's default example code page. There also it does not work as I need. (The cursor does not shift to the next line) which results in multiple br tags to be input as shown in the image below

Raised this issue as a bug report to Tinymce on github too
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/9772

This is only a problem when copying from Notepad or textarea. If you copy from any other source, it should work. If you really need it to go to next line you can append '' or '' in paste_preprocess depending on how args.content ends. But you have to be aware that copying this new text from tinymce back to notepad will have an extra line break.

What do you mean when you say this happens only when I copy from Notepad or text area? where else can I copy from and it works fine?  Because I tried with word too, same behavior is seen then too.

also, adding this logic in the preProcess config will be appenidng br tag to every text I paste to the editor. But it is meaningful only when I paste the contents which has a break at the end of the content. Right?

I tried with Word and it worked as expected. Only issue I had was with Notepad and HTML textarea.  If you copy from Notepad to Word, you get the same issue. When you copy text from Notepad, that has a newLine like you described, it will end with '' or ''. In paste_preprocess you have to check if it is one of the two cases and add one more '' or ''. If its not one of the two cases, you do nothing...

Which version of tinymce did you try with?
